# React Native ternary/conditional operator error - "Raw Text cannot be used outside <Text> tag"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Having an issue implementing a ternary operator in my React Native code.

```
render() {
  const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <Card key={index}>
          <Image
              style={[styles.image_card]}
              source={{uri: item.url}} />
          <View>
            {item.is_rtp_resto ?
                null : <Text>hi</Text>
            } 
          </View>
        </Card>
```

`collections` is an array with fields like this:

```
 {
   "is_rtp_resto": false,
   "item_name": "Chicken tikka masala",
   "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/grubhub/image/upload/v1511880272/yotwhnbr9hsnnkmfydm3.jpg"
 },
```

However, the error I'm getting is `Raw text cannot be used outside of a <text> tag. Not rendering string: ''`. I'm having trouble figuring out where that could be, because i don't have empty '' anywhere...

What am I doing wrong in the `item.is_rtp_resto ?` call? If i take that out I have no issues (item.url among other fields are coming in fine and everything).

Thanks!

MORE INFO:

If I remove the

```
      <View>
        {item.is_rtp_resto ?
            null : <Text>hi</Text>
        } </View>
```

entirely, then I do not get an error -- so I know something in that little section with the operator or how I am calling .is_rtp_resto must be causing the error...

Here is the full body of the mapping iterator. As you can see below, any calls to other attributes in the array (.url, .item_name) work fine.

```
  const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <Card key={index}>
          <Image
              style={[styles.image_card]}
              source={{uri: item.url}} />
              <View>
                {item.is_rtp_resto ?
                  null : <Text>hi</Text>
              } </View>
           <View>
               <Text style={styles.label}>{item.item_name}</Text>
           </View>
        </Card>
    )
  });
```

Comment: I am not seeing what could be the problem here, are you sure that the error is here? Can you add more code?

Comment: just tried it with '' instead of null so that it is `<View>
                {item.is_rtp_resto ?
                    '' : <Text>hi</Text>
                } </View>` instead --- still the same Raw Text error.

Comment: hey @MarioNikolaus -- I added a section under MORE INFO. I know this is the troublesome part of the code because if I remove that little section, nothing errors and it renders fine. Let me know if you still need more code.

Comment: what if `<View>{ !item.is_rtp_resto && <Text>hi</Text> }</View>`

Comment: Cherniv beat me to it, why do you have conditional like that when you can make it more simpler `<View>{item.is_rtp_resto || <Text>hi</Text>}</View>`? And are you sure again that you don't have typo anywhere?

Comment: Doing that makes it work! any idea why that would work but what I had up there (no typo, i double-checked, it's literally the code block i copy pasted) did not? Thanks!

Comment: No clue, but glad you fixed it